# Remove line from geom_smooth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to remove the regression line from geom_smooth and only keep the confidence interval.  I have tried `size = 0`, `size = NULL`, and `size = NA`, but none work.  Is there a simple workaround that anyone knows?

```
baseball <- ddply(x, .(id), transform, bat.avg = h/ab)
hank <- subset(baseball, id == 'aaronha01')
ggplot(hank, aes(x = year, y = bat.avg)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.2, color = '#336699') +
  geom_smooth(fill = '#bf3030', size = NA) +
  labs(x = '', y = '')
```

[image: Hank Aaron's Batting Average]

Comment: In general, for more control you can first compute the linear model outside ggplot2, and plot the result manually. @Didzis answer is much easier though in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set `linetype=0` inside `geom_smooth()` to remove line.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))+geom_smooth(linetype=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

setting `size=0` also removes the line. And obviously `size= NA` too.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(wt,mpg))+geom_smooth(size=0)
```