# Remove the trend line caused by geom_smooth in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to remove the trend line which is created while using geom_smooth. The expectation is to just get the confidence interval without the trend line.

I am not sure how to go about with it, can someone help me out?

The data frame I am working with is:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(19389, 19417, 19448, 19478, 
19509, 19539, 19570, 19601, 19631, 19662, 19692, 19723, 19754, 
19783, 19814, 19844, 19875, 19905), class = "Date"), Qty = c(34810, 
34963.3333333333, 35513.3333333333, 36946.6666666667, 38803.3333333333, 
38618.3333333333, 40798.3333333333, 42645, 44686.6666666667, 
46246.6666666667, 43283.3333333333, 40358.3333333333, 39831.6666666667, 
40233.3333333333, 40680, 41103.3333333333, 41446.6666666667, 
41683.3333333333)), row.names = 2:19, class = "data.frame")
```

The code I wrote for this is given below:

```
Subset <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/File.xlsx")

ggplot(Subset,aes(x=Date,y=`Qty`))+
  geom_point(color="purple",size=4,pch=20) +
  geom_line(linetype="dashed") +
  geom_smooth()
```

The plot that arises due to this is given below:

[image]

Need to remove the blue trend line which I have marked for better understanding.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134425/remove-line-from-geom-smooth-in-ggplot2#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20linetype%3D0%20inside%20geom_smooth()%20to%20remove%20line. `linetype = 0` is another option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be acheived by setting the smoother colour to NA, i.e.:

```
ggplot(Subset,aes(x=Date,y=`Qty`))+
  geom_point(color="purple",size=4,pch=20) +
  geom_line(linetype="dashed") +
  geom_smooth(colour=NA)
```

[image: Output plot]

Answer (score 2):

Use `linetype = "blank"`.

From the [Aesthetic specifications](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#sec:line-type-spec),

> Line types can be specified with:
>
> An integer or name: 0 = blank, 1 = solid, 2 = dashed, 3 = dotted, 4
> = dotdash, 5 = longdash, 6 = twodash

```r
library(ggplot2)

Subset <-
    structure(list(
        Date = structure(
            c(
                19389,
                19417,
                19448,
                19478,
                19509,
                19539,
                19570,
                19601,
                19631,
                19662,
                19692,
                19723,
                19754,
                19783,
                19814,
                19844,
                19875,
                19905
            ),
            class = "Date"
        ),
        Qty = c(
            34810,
            34963.3333333333,
            35513.3333333333,
            36946.6666666667,
            38803.3333333333,
            38618.3333333333,
            40798.3333333333,
            42645,
            44686.6666666667,
            46246.6666666667,
            43283.3333333333,
            40358.3333333333,
            39831.6666666667,
            40233.3333333333,
            40680,
            41103.3333333333,
            41446.6666666667,
            41683.3333333333
        )
    ),
    row.names = 2:19,
    class = "data.frame")

ggplot(Subset, aes(x = Date, y = `Qty`)) +
    geom_point(color = "purple",
               size = 4,
               pch = 20) +
    geom_line(linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_smooth(linetype = "blank")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set `colour` to "transparent"

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df,aes(x=Date,y=`Qty`))+
  geom_point(color="purple",size=4,pch=20) +
  geom_line(linetype="dashed") +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE, colour = "transparent")
```

[image]